Making python exe file with using pyinstaller --icon option doesn't change file explorer icon
The exe file's taskbar icon and properties icon changed as set, but the icon in Windows File Explorer didn't change.
The windows file explorer icon is still the default Python exe icon.
I read all the questions on stackoverflow about this problem, but none of them helped.
I created a Python exe with an icon using the pyinstaller command below.
pyinstaller.exe --windowed --onefile --clean --runtime-tmpdir=. --hidden-import pyperclip3 --icon="logo.ico" -n TEST test.py

You are passing string to --icon flag but --icon flag require path of your icon file.
Like This:
pyinstaller.exe --windowed --onefile --clean --runtime-tmpdir=. --hidden-import pyperclip3 --icon=path/to/icon/logo.inc -n TEST test.py
replace path/to/icon with proper relative or absolute path to your icon file.
